# nginx multiple static content servers on subdomains with url rewrite

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have one server with nginx-frontend and apache-backend.

I need to set up nginx to return images from the other two servers like

```
http://example.com/images/*.jpg -> http://i1.example.com/images/*.jpg
```

```
http://example.com/images/*.jpg -> http://i2.example.com/images/*.jpg
```

image folder is the same on both servers.

earlier I asked this question and get answer to put

```
 
upstream backend { 
    server i1.example.com;
    server i2.example.com;
}
```

location /images/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend/;
    #rest of config
}
 
in my config. It work.

but I need some other solution, need to see i1.example.com and i2.example.com in headers,now I see only example.com header. Is it possible? 
I would be grateful for any advice.